# In SynExpr.Lambda, what is the usage of args/body vs. parsedData?

Tags: f#

In FSharp.Compiler.Service, `SynExpr.Lambda` is defined like this:

```
/// First bool indicates if lambda originates from a method. Patterns here are always "simple"
/// Second bool indicates if this is a "later" part of an iterated sequence of lambdas
/// parsedData keeps original parsed patterns and expression,
/// prior to transforming to "simple" patterns and iterated lambdas
///
/// F# syntax: fun pat -> expr
| Lambda of
    fromMethod: bool *
    inLambdaSeq: bool *
    args: SynSimplePats *
    body: SynExpr *
    parsedData: (SynPat list * SynExpr) option *
    range: range *
    trivia: SynExprLambdaTrivia
```

I am implementing an F# linter (i.e., a source code analyzer). I am confused about the usage of `args`/`body` vs. `parsedData`.

My understanding is that `args`/`body` is a simplified version of `parsedData`, and may therefore not correspond to what is in the source file. Therefore, since I am implementing a linter, I should use `parsedData`.

However, `parsedData` is `option`-wrapped, and I have no idea when it may be `None` or what I should do then.

Could anyone clear up the usage of `args`/`body` vs. `parsedData` in the context of implementing a linter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understainding is entirely correct! The rationale for adding that field is explained in this PR: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/10166

> Keeps initially parsed lambda patterns and expressions in the syntax tree.
>
> The parser replaces patterns and expression with iterated lambdas that
> are later used by the type checker and code generation. Ideally this
> conversion should be done at a later stage, so the syntax tree keeps
> the actually parsed data instead. Doing so would make a lot of churn,
> since at this point every other part of the compiler already assumes
> to work with the iterated lambdas.
>
> The problem with this early conversion approach is tools interested in
> the syntax tree try to "reconstruct" the original lambdas, each one
> using a different approach (e.g. FSharpLint, Fantomas). This may be
> error-prone due to in some of the cases the compiler effectively
> throws the tree data away (by stripping parens and errors in various
> cases).
>
> This PR adds another field to SynExpr.Lambda so tooling interested in
> the syntax tree would be able to work with parsed data.

It does not explain what to do when the `parsedData` is `None`. Since the purpose of the `parsedData` is to support Fantomas etc. (not compiling code), I presume that it was made optional for easier backward compatibility.

If you are writing a linter, I would suggest using the `parsedData` if present and either skipping, crashing or using the other fields as a fall-back.

Indeed, skipping is what Fantomas [appears to do](https://github.com/fsprojects/fantomas/blob/main/src/Fantomas.Core/ASTTransformer.fs#L871-L872):

```ml
    | SynExpr.Lambda(_, _, _, _, Some(pats, body), _, { ArrowRange = Some mArrow }) ->
        mkLambda creationAide pats mArrow body exprRange |> Expr.Lambda
```